# Windows 10 extremely slow boot from shut down or restart, not hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

I have a dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04, Asus republic of gamers, GL753V, one of the best gaming laptops, Windows OS is installed on SSD.

After selecting windows from grub menu, I see loading spinner on black screen. This thing for the past week or two  is lasting between or 15 minutes from shutdown, and around a minute from hibernate I think.

In other words, if I were to shutdown or restart windows, then it would take longer to get to the login screen than windows XP on pentium 3, for real.

Once I get to the login screen, everything becomes extremely fast, how to know why getting to login screen is getting so long?

I have only 3 programs running on startup, Logitech mouse drivers, Avast and windows defender which has low impact since it's not doing anything. Very few programs are installed too on this pc.

I disabled fastboot, the problem is the same, I also trying restarting and shutting down again, the same problem, I also did full scan using avast free version and malwarebytes premium version, No malware found, the problem still exists.

Comment: Is this after a clean install of windows?

Have you installed "Intel Management Engine Interface", I have seen performance issues whilst windows installed drivers show no errors in device manager some functionality of the motherboard can show unexpected behaviour like SATA controller etc.

Comment: @CraftyB not a clean installed, been using it for 6 months or so. I have ""Intel Management Engine Interface" installed, should I uninstall it? Those are all intel related software installed https://imgur.com/a/JEOAJ4g

Comment: As you have it already installed I dont think this will be the cause, have you recently installed updates? Have you tried disabling "Fast Boot" in the power options?, What is your virtual memory / page file size configured to?, how old is the SSD/Laptop?

Comment: @CraftyB All updates have been installed in the last 2 days, I'm not in windows insider program so only stable updates. virtual memory is 1856 MB. Fast boot is enabled and I haven't tried to disable it yet.I don't know how to determine how old is SSD, but I think the laptop is released in 2017, I bought it new, around 6 or 8 month ago

Comment: Right ok, could you please try and disable fast boot, there has been numerous reports of this causing adverse affects, could you also confirm if the problem is apparent when restarting and shutting down the computer as shutting down alone saves your current state to speed up startup but this can also be problematic. Your virtual memory is fine at the setting it is. The reason I question the age of the SSD is that if they have alot of writes this eventually causes the SSD to fail and in some cases immediately fail with no ability to read.

Comment: @CraftyB I disabled fastboot, the problem is the same, I also trying restarting and shutting down again, the same problem, I also did full scan using avast free version and malwarebytes premium version, No malware found, the problem still exists.

Comment: I would suggest making windows partition handle the bootloading, I missed this initially, GRUB may have its own issues with loading into windows as where the comparison the other way around does not to be so bad, I will try to find a link to reverse the bootloading with straight forward steps!

Comment: @CraftyB I too get this feeling that it's caused by grub, thank you so much, waiting for your answer

Comment: For completeness, check the disk for S.M.A.R.T. errors and look in the Windows Event Viewer for useful messages. Try to boot Windows in Safe Mode, and also try boot in Debugging Mode.

Comment: "I see loading spinner on black screen" - is it Windows logon screen? or bootloader's loading screen?

Comment: @XX no just a black screen

Answer (score 0):

Here are few possible causes

1. **Device or driver**
   Try to unplug all external devices (e.g. USB headset, mouse, printers, etc). If problem gets fixed, then plug back half of them and so on to determine faulty device/driver.
   After finding faulty device, first check if it works on other computer. If works, then problem may be in driver - try to reinstall or rollback the driver.
2. **Network - sync, network profiles, network printers, search for network boot**
   Windows may stop on booting or login screen when trying to perform network related job (e.g. can check network boot options or try to sync data). To make sure this is not the case, go to your BIOS settings and disable all network cards (WiFi, LAN), reboot. (Try it, if it gets fixed, then can provide more steps to find out exact cause).
3. **Boot loader**
   Can be caused while Windows bootloader tries to read OS list (or something similar).
   Try to set Windows as default boot loader option, and disable list of other OSes in Windows boot loader.
   Go to boot options from Control Panel => System => Advanced System Settings => Advanced => click "Settings" button in "Startup and Recovery" part.
   Then select Windows as default OS and uncheck "Time to display list of operating systems"
   [image: Default OS]

Try these steps to see if they help. Will update with more details and steps if necessary.